# Xamarin Carousel view messes up binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, carousel

So i have a view which is a content page and in this view i include a contentview which works fine. Now if i move this content view into a carousel view the binding no longer works.

So to be clear following works as expected:

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <views:EventBasicInfoView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The following displays just fine but none of the data is bound.

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <CarouselView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type ContentView}">
                    <views:EventBasicInfoView/>
                </x:Array>
            </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Content="{Binding .}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Any advice on what to do would be much appreciated

Comment: each view in any templated control gets its BindingContext from the currently active item from it's itemsource

Comment: Right and in this case binding context is null. If i move the view outside of the carousel the binding context is bound to view model that content page is bound to?

Comment: yes, because you have a ContentView that is bound to EventBasicInfoView

Comment: But why would moving the view ref out of carousel change the binding context?

Comment: because normally an Element inherits its parent's BindingContext.  When in a template it gets the BindingContext from the current element of itemsSource

Comment: @MaxqueueMa According to your description, you add contentview in CarouselView ItemsSource, and using binding to display these contentview, I try it and have no problems, so if you still have this question, please show your EventBasicInfoView code, or you bind viewmodel to ContentPage? Please show more detailed code.